# Cache API will be removed by April 2020

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

We are using the latest version of extjs. The Cache API warning baffles us since it is said to be removed this month(April 2020).
How do we avoid that or what should we do to remove the warning?
Thanks.

> Application Cache API use is deprecated and will be removed in M82,
>   around April 2020. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6192449487634432 for more
>   details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExtJs Application Cache warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969506/extjs-application-cache-warning)

Comment: Remove the warning will not work until Sencha makes changes to Sencha CMD

Comment: ok. thanks as long as the warning won't damage anything, that's fine